# Send email and sms django phone auth

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm using the [django-phone-auth](https://django-phone-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for authentication, but I can't figure out how to send email verification and phone verification

```
  # for email
  from django.dispatch import receiver
  from phone_auth.signals import verify_email

  @receiver(verify_email)
  def verify_email_signal(sender, user, url, email, **kwargs):
     ...
     # Send email
     ...


  #for phone
  from django.dispatch import receiver
  from phone_auth.signals import verify_phone

  @receiver(verify_phone)
  def verify_phone_signal(sender, user, url, phone, **kwargs):
    ...
    # Send SMS
    ...
```

the documentation says this.
How can i send email and phone ??
please help me ))

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
 from phone_auth.signals import verify_phone
from sms import send_sms

@receiver(verify_phone)
def verify_phone_signal(sender, user, url, phone, **kwargs):
send_sms(
'Hello', # body
'+myphonenumber', # originator
[user.phone], #recipients
fail_silently=False
)
```

and this function produces [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWa3f.png) in console and this is all what it do

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a view [override](https://django-phone-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#phone-e-mail-verification)?

I haven't seen this package in general, but I can see that it uses signals that have a user in the argument. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/), sending an email would look something like this.

```
# for email
  from django.dispatch import receiver
  from phone_auth.signals import verify_email
  from django.core.mail import send_mail


  @receiver(verify_email)
  def verify_email_signal(sender, user, url, email, **kwargs):
     send_mail(
         'Subject here',
         'Here is the message.',
         'from@example.com',
         [user.email],
         fail_silently=False,
      )
```

**UPDATE**

I think you need to use additional `modules`. The `library` you use authorizes messages, but does not allow you to send `sms` (at least I didn't find any such information).

However, I found a `backend` that seems optimal for you. Referring to the [documentation there](https://pypi.org/project/django-sms/), try to send a text message this way.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from phone_auth.signals import verify_phone
from sms import send_sms

@receiver(verify_phone)
def verify_phone_signal(sender, user, url, phone, **kwargs):
    send_sms(
    'Your message', # body
    '+12065550100', # originator
    [user.phone_number], #recipients
    fail_silently=False
    )
```

**UPDATE #2**
I wrote to you to read the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-sms/). It clearly says

> Instead of **sending out real text messages** the console backend just
> writes the text messages that would be sent to the **standard output**. By
> default, the console backend **writes to stdout**. You can use a different
> stream-like object by providing the stream keyword argument when
> constructing the connection.

Use one of the listed backend, for example.

```
SMS_BACKEND = 'sms.backends.twilio.SmsBackend'
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'live_redacted-twilio-account-sid'
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'live_redacted-twilio-auth-token'
```

Comment: hello how can i do SMS notification?

Comment: I think in an analogous way. If the solution from a week ago works, accept it.

Comment: Yes this work, but this is not work for send SMS. And i don't find any library to send SMS in django.

Comment: If the email solution works, the phone option must also work. Show us what it looks like in your code.

Comment: How i can show you my code if i ask about how can i do this??

Comment: Edit the post and add new information.

Comment: How can I show you my code if I have not done it yet I ask you how to make SMS notification

Comment: If the e-mail notification works, try substituting it with the data from the sms notifications.

Comment: This is not work for sms!

Comment: You can edit your answer, adding new information, code or screenshots. Maybe something else can be worked out.

Comment: Can you do this ? SMS notification ?

Comment: Check out my updated answer above. @ce6ergtiz

Comment: Yes I see, but they don't actually work and all they do is:
from: +#
to: +#
Hello
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[26/Jul/2022 21:40:47] "POST /accounts/user_verification/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
[26/Jul/2022 21:40:54] "POST /accounts/user_verification/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2580
from: +#
to: +#
Hello

Comment: It's hard to deduce anything from what you posted. Format the text and upload the code with screenshots.

Comment: I have added new information

Comment: Check my second update.